# Why does a double sudo modify permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

#### Context:

`ssh`ed into an AWS t1.micro instance running Amazon Linux 2013.09, using the default `ec2-user`.  I'm trying to list the contents of the default postgresql directory:

*What's in there?*

```
$ ls /var/lib/pgsql9/

ls: cannot open directory /var/lib/pgsql9/: Permission denied
```

*Ok.  Who owns this?*

```
$ ls -l /var/lib | grep pgsql
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres 4096 Jun 22 16:06 pgsql9
```

*Ah.  Silly me.*

```
$ sudo -u postgres ls /var/lib/pgsql9/

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for ec2-user:
```

*... What? `ec2-user` has a password? Time for a bigger gun.*

```
$ sudo sudo -u postgres ls /var/lib/pgsql9/
backups  data
```

***Success!***  Now, off to superuser.com to figure out what happened.

#### Why does `sudo sudo` behave differently than `sudo`?

Comment: You know, `sudo ls /var/lib/pgsql9` would work too. `root` can access stuff even if it's not in the permissions

Comment: Thanks! I feel pretty silly for not trying that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon EC2 is built like Ubuntu: no `root` access and everything is done with `sudo` instead.

What your `sudo` command did was try to impersonate `postgres`, requiring permission to do so. `ec2-user` does not have this permission, so `sudo` will ask for a password (which will fail because it doesn't have one).

When you did `sudo sudo`, you are invoking the second `sudo` as root which has the permissions to impersonate other users, so the command works. Because of the way `sudo` is configured (the NOPASSWD line in sudoers) it doesn't need a password to execute as root.

Comment: I had to read that a couple of times.  So, `myuser@1.2.3.4 $ sudo <command>` executes the `<command>` as `root`, and the `sudo` command sees `myuser` as the executor of `sudo`.  Chaining them as `myuser@1.2.3.4 $ sudo sudo ...` means that the inner `sudo` sees `root` as the executor, who has permission to impersonate any user.  Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: this saved my day.